# Bad Words in America

Tags: american-english

Why are cuss words bad? Like, they are just like any other word. And how come when people get mad, cussing helps them feel better?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's probably too big for [elu.se] (and perhaps too basic at the same time). Also, this isn't an issue strictly of American English, or even just English. You might be better off reading up on this somewhere like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profanity).

Comment: They're not called *cuss words* unless they are bad.

Comment: This question appears to be about the linguistics of profanity in general, not about English.

Comment: Just because you are having problems with your brother (or mom), should not prompt you to search out this site to vent your frustration.

Answer (score 0):

One theory goes like this:

I use words that cause bad feelings or shock as a way to communicate my own bad feeling or shock.

The bad words emphasise something that the culture doesn't like, or finds shocking. Depending on the culture, this might mean body parts, body functions, religious topics, sexual practices, disease, and so on.

There's much more to it than that, but that's the gist.

Incidentally, Japanese rarely swear: they don't need to. Japanese has so many nuances of politeness and vulgarity that, just by picking the "wrong" verb ending, you can cause shock and offence.

More info here: http://www.openculture.com/2012/08/steven_pinker_explains_the_neuroscience_of_swearing.html

Comment: Thanks for the Pinker link.  And the Japanese reference.  The only thing I learned about Japanese verbs is that there's one form that's reserved for the Emperor.  (Or was.)

Answer (score 0):

Another angle:  curse words are usually the result of anger, and are often directed towards someone else.

Besides that, given English's 200,000-plus word count, people who use a lot of curse words are seen as less educated.

It's not true that they're "just like any other word".   George Carlin had a famous monologue "Seven Dirty Words"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words

(I don't know if you consider "cuss words" in the same category as those seven.)